# Relation between the inverse of finitely generated ideals and the inverse of their powers.

Tags: commutative-algebra

> Let $D$ be an integral domain, $K$ its field of fractions, and $J_1,...,J_n$ are ideals of $D$ such that $(\sum_{i=1}^{n} J_i)^{-1}=D$. How can we prove that this implies $(\sum_{i=1}^{n} J_i^m)^{-1}=D$ for all $m\ge1$ ?

I know that the converse is true since $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{J_i}^{m}\subseteq\sum_{i=1}^{n}J_i$. I tried to prove it by induction on $m$ but it did not work.
This question is part of the proof of the lemma 4.2 in the the paper [Some remarks on star-operations](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404980901140) by Hedstorm and Houston.

Comment: I have to say that I am a novice in the subject of the stars-operations, I try to understand the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $x\in (D:_K \sum_{i=1}^{n} J_i)$ iff $xJ_i\subseteq D$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$.

Let me prove the case $n=2$. I'll show that

> $(J_1+J_2)^{-1}=D$ implies $(J_1^{m_1}+J_2^{m_2})^{-1}=D$ for any $m_1,m_2\ge 1$.

First set $m_1=1$. Then pick an $x\in(J_1+J_2^{m_2})^{-1}$, so $xJ_1\subset D$ and $xJ_2^{m_2}\subset D$. Since $(xJ_2)J_2^{m_2-1}\subset D$, and $(xJ_2)J_1\subset D$, by induction we get $xJ_2\subset D$, hence $x\in(J_1+J_2)^{-1}=D$. Now use induction on $m_1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.